# Soft-keyboard makes the cordova-view shrink

Tags: android, cordova, zooming, android-softkeyboard

In my cordova-powered app I disabled the zoom. Though on a page with an input field, if the soft-keyboard shows-up, the view gets automatically zoomed to include the whole page:

[image: Start state]

[image: with soft-keyboard]

when the soft-keyboard disappears, the page remains zoomed.

How to get rid of this zooming? I took a look at `softkeyboard plugin` but it didn't give me any hints...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found an answer myself. I had to add the `windowSoftInputMode` attribute to make it work:

```
    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
        ....
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" >
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your own solution. It helped me with my problem.

Comment: Thank you so much!!