# Cordova disable shrink view on input focus

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, cordova

I'm creating an app in Cordova/Phonegap (v6.5.0).
Platforms installed:
    - IOS (problem is present)
    - Android (problem is present)
    - Browser (problem is not present)

Now I have a known problem, but no adequate fix for it.

When I focus on a field on my page, the whole page tries to fit on the view the user has (between the top bar and the virtual keyboard). This makes my fields overlapping each other and making the app ugly.

What I would like to have is that my page stays the same, so not adapting to the keyboard.

Do any of you have a solution for this? I have this on all my pages.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

I found the answer by myself on the following link: [Soft-keyboard makes the cordova-view shrink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715485/soft-keyboard-makes-the-cordova-view-shrink?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

The cross platform *(iOS and Android)* solution to this problem is to install the following plugin:

```
cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard --save
```

And add the following code to your `deviceready` handler:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){

    if (window.cordova && cordova.plugins && cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
});
```

**Note:** Ignore the fact it's an [iconic plugin](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-keyboard), it works fine with regular cordova projects